# Another phrase for "Fear Hacking"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, synonyms

I am trying to give a speech on dissecting and understand what one is afraid of. I came up with the title "Fear Hacking". I am looking to use another word for "hacking" so my audience can understand what I am trying to say with my title alone. I need the word to be have a positive connotation and I have posted below some of the words that capture what I am trying to say.

- Conquer your fear
- Dissect your fear

Comment: It seems to me you should only fear hacking if you're a tree.

Comment: 'Use your fear'. Nobody can overcome fear. It is an instinct. It needs to be managed and exploited.Because of my occupation, I am often afraid. It is not a disadvantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ***deconstruct*** your fear.

> **[American Heritage Dictionary:](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=deconstruct)**
>
>   To break down into components; dismantle:
>     a toxic substance that can be deconstructed into harmless chemicals.
>
> **[Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deconstruct)**
>
> - to examine (something, such as a work of literature)
>     using the methods of deconstruction
>
>   to take apart or examine (something)
>     in order to reveal the basis or composition
>     often with the intention of exposing biases, flaws, or inconsistencies
>
>   - *deconstruct* the myths of both the left and the right —Wayne Karlin
>
> **[Oxford English Dictionaries:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/deconstruct)**
>
> - Analyze (a text or a linguistic or conceptual system) by deconstruction,
>     typically in order to expose its hidden internal assumptions and contradictions
>     and subvert its apparent significance or unity.
>
>   Reduce (something) to its constituent parts in order to reinterpret it.
>     *‘do we need to deconstruct all the institutions that we've created
>     in order to improve them?’*

So it seems to mean “conquer by dissecting”.